# Error while trying to access phone camera with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I expected to receive a video feed in my laptop from my phone. In my opinion, the code is correct. The same code is running on other devices. But when I tried doing the same in my laptop, it displayed the following error:

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (142) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): http://192.168.1.3:8080/video in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

Since I am a newbie to the world of opencv, I could'nt understand what caused the error. Hence, I did'nt try anything worthwhile other than changing a few lines of code.
My code is:

```
import cv2
url= 'http://192.168.1.3:8080/video'
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(url)
cap.set(3,240)
cap.set(4,240)
while(True):
   ret,frame=cap.read()
   if frame is not None:
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
   q=cv2.waitKey(1)
   if q==ord("q"):
    break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: What re the other devices you mean ?

Comment: I meant that it is running on my friends' devices. I had sent the same code to them. Actually it ran on my device too 2 days back. But it isn't running now

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same issue but with a a saved video file as the input.
The file path I had entered did no exist and I got the same error.
I would suggest to check if your have given the right permissions to for accessing your phone's camera and if the feed is live and is returning images in the correct format.